# How do I get my content to look good on mobile without meta tags?

Tags: html, mobile, meta-tags

I'm building a small ad unit for a customer. It generates a HTML popup, and displays it on the page. The problem is when pages implement this ad unit, but don't have the viewport meta tag, the popup appears too small.
Is there an easy way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create meta viewport tag dynamically with javascript.

```
<script>
var elem = document.createElement("meta");
elem.name = "viewport";
elem.content = "bla bla bla..";
document.head.appendChild(elem);
</script>
```

And then use `@media queries.`

Comment: Won't this also affect the content on the website?